# How to increase the labels at runtime

Tags: iphone

i am accessing the web services, which return me data in a string array.
now i am creating a label at runtime, and adding it to the view of the application.
but for eg if there are 3 recodrs, only the third value is displayed in the label.
i mean to say i want to add labels one below the other.
how am i to do it...

i declared NSInteger *y=172;
and created a label
UILabel * l1=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11,y+50,302,98)];
I dont know...whether it is correct .... but it surely gives me an error incompatible type for argument 2 of CGRextMake

Answer (score 2):

I think your error lies here:

```
NSInteger *y=172;
```

NSInteger is not an object type, it should be:

```
NSInteger y = 172;
```